# ArcMap - wrong/no features selected when using select tools

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, select

All of a sudden my features aren't selecting properly when using the "select by rectangle" tool. Previously, I could click on an individual point feature and that feature would be selected.  If I enclosed a group of points with the rectangle, each of these point features would be selected (as expected).  For some reason, this selection behavior is not working.  It is as if **each point feature has an invisible line extending some distance to the right**, and if that line intersects the "select by" rectangle, then the point feature is included in the selection.

This behavior is consistent for all feature classes, regardless of geometry.

If it helps. . .
Many of my feature classes have heavily edited tables (field edits) and geometries (point features moved)
I am using ArcGIS for Desktop v10.6 (Windows 10)
My data is all stored in a file geodatabase.

Comment: Sounds like time to close and restart ArcMap to test this on a new simple map.  If it works there try your actual map again.

Comment: There's a few things that could be wrong here, as PolyGeo said, your MXD may be broken - close and restart, if the problem persists try the data in a new ArcMap session, if it's still not working then it could be a problem with your spatial index - rebuild http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000060000000 the index, or a problem with your geometries (incorrect ring order), use Repair Geometry to fix that http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003v000000, if you still have problems don't dispair (yet), that's just the common fixes.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Unfortunately, it looks like whatever the problem is is related to the actual data, as opening the same feature classes into a new blank map results in the same behavior.  Might be time to start over from scratch.